# How do I point my new version installation of my WPF application at a SQL Server CE database

Tags: wpf, sql-server-ce

I have a WPF application that has been working quite well. This application has a SQL Server CE database that saves some content for the user.

For clarity the current application is called Version 1.

I recently edited Version 1 to include new functionality so thus in effect the WPF application is now Version 2.

Version 1 includes a SQL Server CE database that saves some data for the user.

In Version 2 I only added some functionality. So what I am trying to achieve is that Version 2 points to SQL Server CE database of the prior Version 1 application that was installed.

Currently when I deploy Version 2 it creates a new SQL Server CE database and does NOT point to the Version 1 SQL Server CE Database as I was hoping.

The reason I want to point to the Version 1 SQL Server CE database is that the user have used Version 1 extensively and I do not want them to lose their data.

I hope this makes my query a bit more clear.

Please could anyone point me in the right direction.

Kind regards,
geo

Comment: Not clear.  You stop using Version 1 and Version 2 syntax.  What does "overwriting the current SQL Server CE database and all the info within" mean.  Please be clear on what is happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: Did you try setting the LocalConnectionString?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173385(v=SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Hi Blam well as I understand it WPF increments each build of the application. So if Version 1 has manifest build of (eg) 0.0.0.89 version 2 will have an increment of 0.0.0.90. So pointing the LocalConnectionString to the correct manifest build whould be the chanllenge I suppose.